# provide connection to jdbc template

Tags: java, spring, jdbc

I am facing a use case that I have not ran into before with respect to using the jdbc template. I looked all over the web and also here, but can't find an answer to my use case.

In the current framework that I am using which was developed at the company I am currently working at, jdbc connections are readily availabe and obtained in the following format:

```
ConnectionManager.getInstance().getConnection(some_database_name);
```

The database name is a parameter provided and it can be different at times.

So in order to use the jdbc template, I created a sub class of the commons dbcp data source and added a constructor which takes in the connection above

```
public CommonsDBCPExtension(Connection conn) {
    this.conn = conn;
}
```

Then I just instantiate a jdbc template and set the datasource:

```
this.jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate();
jdbcTemplate.setDataSource(CommonsDBCPExtension);
```

After that so far all my tests are working. The reason I want to stick with the jdbc template is so that I can avoid all the nightmare jdbc code that I'll have to write which in my opinion is worse than what I have done so far.

So I am wondering if there is a more elegant way of doing this in spring, or this is just flat out wrong, or if it's the right approach. This is the first time I have run into this use case in my career, so a bit of help from anyone who has had experience with something like this would be greatly appreciated.